# Cluster Tooltip to display list of features

Tags: qgis

Trying to work out how to make the tool tip show a list of features represented by a Point Cluster. When I use identify on a Point Cluster it provides a list of the features in that cluster to identify. Just trying to make the same list appear on mouse over. QGIS 3.4

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing this problem as well.